# Selenium + BS4 retrieve hidden element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I wrote the following code to retrieve a div with the class "tab-statistics-1-statistic". This one is nested in the "statistics-content" div.

```
soup.find(id="statistics-content").find(id="tab-statistics-1-statistic")
```

But when I print the output of the above line it only returns "div id='statistics-content'>" even though in "Inspect element" the div contains nested elements. The page used for this code is https://www.flashscore.com/match/CM2dBaSF/#match-summary

[image: Inspect element of page]

How can I get access to the nested elements within the div ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are navigating to landing page but need to click through to the statistics tab to generate the required html. You need to allow time for javascript to run to populate info.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
d = webdriver.Chrome()
url ='https://www.flashscore.com/match/CM2dBaSF/#match-summary'

d.get(url)
d.find_element_by_id('a-match-statistics').click()
item = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID , 'tab-statistics-0-statistic')))
print(item.text)
d.quit()
```

---

As a new url is generated for the stats tab you can just use that direct instead

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
d = webdriver.Chrome()
urlDirect = 'https://www.flashscore.com/match/CM2dBaSF/#match-statistics;0'
d.get(urlDirect)
item = WebDriverWait(d, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID , 'tab-statistics-0-statistic')))
print(item.text)
d.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the browser and the dev tools you will be getting those values, because the browser might have already loaded the content. You will have to emulate the same behavior when using selenium. Wait for some time till the content is loaded in the selenium web driver by using 
`WebDriverwait`

The sample code below.

`driver=driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.flashscore.com/match/CM2dBaSF/#match-statistics;0')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID ,'tab-statistics-1-statistic')
html = driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.find(id="statistics-content").find(id="statistics-1-statistic"))`

Sample output

`<li class="li1" id="statistics-1-statistic"><span><a onclick="detail_tab(['statistics', '1-statistic']);">1st Half</a></span></li>`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you are using another URL than I am. I use https://www.flashscore.com/match/CM2dBaSF/#match-summary as described in the post

Comment: Can you please let me know how are you getting to the statistics tab in the page ? The url that i shared is the direct link to the statistics tab. I am not sure how you would be able to load the statistics tab without navigating to the same ? Even if you start with the original url that you shared, you will have to navigate to the statistics tab inorder to get the content within.